# Compile Less file using less.js on run time

Tags: less

I have multiple less files like variables.less, custom.less etc into variables.less files I have declared a @base variable and used in into different less file. Now we need to compile these less files using less.js and jquery so that if any user change @base color at run time then the theme change at run time. Is these any way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less variable issue in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246808/less-variable-issue-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your `.less` files You want separately, then, make one to import and compile, for example `libs.less`

In that file, You may want to import all your other Less files; for example:

```
@import "common.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "colors.less";
@import "otherlessfile.less";
```

Then compile... I use [Winless](http://winless.org/), a very nice and easy to use compiler.

pd: This is my first answer here, regards ;)